# Javascript async method issue with a callback function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Have the following called library:

```
var rd = require('redis.dump')
```

used in function to query the database and do some processing and then return

```
function query(type, row, column){
  var output = []
  ...
  rd({
      filter: ...
      port  : ...
      format:  ...
      },
      function(err, result){
       [where the processing of result begins]
       ...
       output = [processed result]
       ...
      }
     });
  return output;
  }
```

How to out async in place to wait until rd finishes and then return output?
I tried the following and failed:

```
function query(type, row, column){
  var output = []
  ...
  rd({
      filter: ...
      port  : ...
      format:  ...
      },
      async function convert(err, result){
       [where the processing of result begins]
       ...
       output = [processed result]
       ...
      }
     });
  rd.convert.then(return output);
  }
```

with a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `rd.convert` doesn’t make sense. `rd` is a function, not an object with a `convert` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
// replace your code into this 
function query(type, row, column,cb){
  var output = []
  ...
  rd({
      filter: ...
      port  : ...
      format:  ...
      },
      function(err, result){
       [where the processing of result begins]
       ...
       output = [processed result]
       // call callback function and pass output result
       cb(output)
      }
     });
  }
```

**// to call this function write**

```
query(type, row, column,function(output){
  console.log(output)

})
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, it works. how to assign output to variable outside function query.?

Comment: this is async process so that any thing you want to do must be in callback function